# Duplicate 'contained' elements in generated message - HAPI FHIR DSTU2HL7Org

Tags: java, hl7-fhir, hapi

I am using HAPI FHIR DSTU2HL7Org to create MedicationOrders in a remote server. The construction of the object is as follows.

```
MedicationOrder[] medicationOrder = null;
MedicationOrderDataWrapper[] medicationOrderWrapper = new MedicationOrderDataToolkit().getMedicationOrderDataWrapper(wrapper);

if(medicationOrderWrapper != null)
{
  medicationOrder = new MedicationOrder[medicationOrderWrapper.length];
  for(int i=0; i<medicationOrderWrapper.length; i++)
  {
    medicationOrder[i] = new MedicationOrder();
    MedicationOrderDosageInstructionComponent dosageInstruction = new MedicationOrderDosageInstructionComponent().setDose(medicationOrderWrapper[i].getDoseQuantity()).
        setTiming(medicationOrderWrapper[i].getTiming()).setAdditionalInstructions(medicationOrderWrapper[i].getAdditionalInstruction());

    medicationOrder[i].addDosageInstruction(dosageInstruction).setEncounterTarget(medicationOrderWrapper[i].getEncounter()).
    setMedication(medicationOrderWrapper[i].getMedicationCodeableConcept()).setPatientTarget(medicationOrderWrapper[i].getPatient()).setPrescriberTarget(medicationOrderWrapper[i].getPractitioner())
    .addExtension(medicationOrderWrapper[i].getExtension());

    medicationOrder[i].getContained().add(medicationOrder[i].getEncounterTarget());
    medicationOrder[i].getContained().add(medicationOrderWrapper[i].getOrganization());
    medicationOrder[i].getContained().add(medicationOrderWrapper[i].getLocation());
    medicationOrder[i].getContained().add(medicationOrder[i].getPatientTarget());
    medicationOrder[i].getContained().add(medicationOrder[i].getPrescriberTarget());

    medicationOrder[i].setEncounter(new Reference("#" + medicationOrder[i].getEncounterTarget().getId()))
    .setPatient(new Reference("#" + medicationOrder[i].getPatientTarget().getId()).setDisplay(medicationOrder[i].getPatientTarget().getName().get(0).getText()))
    .setPrescriber(new Reference("#" + medicationOrder[i].getPrescriberTarget().getId()).setDisplay(medicationOrder[i].getPrescriberTarget().getName().getText()))
    .setReason(medicationOrderWrapper[i].getReasonCodeableConcept()).addIdentifier(medicationOrderWrapper[i].getCosmicIdentifier());
```

But this code results in duplicate contained elements in the generated xml message. Organization and Location elements appear 3 times and 2 times respectively, while Patient, Practitioner and Encounter appears only once.

Can anyone please explain this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This actually just sounds like a bug. Do you mind to file a report on the GitHub issue tracker?

Comment: Thanks Mr. Agnew. I will report a bug.